# Will JMeter wait for the HTTP response of a HTTP sample before running the next one?

Tags: jmeter

Will JMeter wait for a HTTP response code from one HTTP sampler before it executes the HTTP request from the next HTTP sampler in a simple controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It willl wait for the configured timeout which by default is infinite.

So the answer is yes.
If you set a timeout, it will wait for the response to come fir the timeout duration and then will stop, mark the request as timeouted and then call next request.

See:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request